# Deallocate memory from 2D mixed array and vector

Tags: c++, allocation

a 2D and 3D array vectors are defined and used throughout a simulation, they are very large in size so deallocation is neccesary.

```
array<vector<double>, n> A;
array<vector<vector<double>, n>, m> B;
```

what is the proper way?

Comment: Do you want the arrays to go away or the storage of the vectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just let them go out of scope:

```
{
    array<vector<double>, n> A;
    array<vector<vector<double>, n>, m> B;

    // use arrays ...

} // leave scope, arrays will be deallocated
```

Comment: what do u mean? when simulation is done they are deallocated?

Comment: @jarhead they will be deallocated whenever the scope they are defined in is left

Comment: If you put '{}' around your variable, they are deallocated after the '}'.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080935/when-is-an-object-out-of-scope

Comment: @ARG so basically when it is out of main() it is out of scope as well

Comment: Yes, and also if you put them in code like this

`int main() {
 
 {
     array<vector<double>, n> A;
     array<vector<vector<double>, n>, m> B;

     // do whatever you want with them

 } // out of scope so arrays will be deallocated
 
 // do whatever else you want
 
 return 0;
}`

Comment: But IMHO there is no need to deallocate the variable which are allocated on stack