# When are destructors called in c++?

Tags: c++

I know that whenever an object goes **out of scope** or **deleted** compiler automatically calls destructor , but how do I know the scope of an object ?

For e.g. in this code:

```
    #include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class demo
{
    static int count;
public:
    demo()
    {
        cout<<"object created"<<++count<<endl;
    }
    ~demo()
    {
        cout<<"object destroyed"<<count--<<endl;
    }
};
int demo::count;
int main()
{
    cout<<"in main\n";
    demo d1;
    {
        cout<<"in block 1\n";
        demo d2;
        {
            cout<<"in block 2\n";
            demo d3;
        }
    }
    {
        cout<<"in block 3\n";
        demo d4;
    }
    cout<<"exit\n";
}
```

What is the scope of each object?

Comment: did you try actually compiling and running this code?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080935/when-is-an-object-out-of-scope

Comment: Doing this by order:

The constructors get called: demo d1 -> demo d2 -> demo d3 -> demo d4.

The destructors get called: -> demo d3 -> demo d2 -> demo d4 -> demo d1.

The reason that happens, it's because each { } has its own set of start and finish addresses on the stack frame. Every time you meet a new object, it gets created under the necessary scope ( { } ). When you leave that scope, it gets called by the destructor (unless it was allocated, or configured as  a static variable.) So the outputs of each one :

Comment: Constructors && Destructors Combined->

object created 1

object created 2

object created 3

object destroyed 3

object destroyed 2

object created 2 (Means object 4)

object destroyed 2 (Means object 4)

object destroyed 1

Out of just looking at the code, maybe something wrong here or there.

Answer (score 1):

The scope of an object is when it leaves the `{ }` in which it has been declared. This is for local variables, not for static and global one.

In your ecample, the objects will leave the scope in this order: `d3` `d2` `d4` and `d1`. Plese remark that `d1` and `d4` are in the same scope and the rule for deleting the objects in same scope is in inverse order of the allocation.

Answer (score 0):

The objects in C++ can be created either on the stack or on on the heap.

A stack frame (or scope) is defined by a statement. That can be as big as a function or as small as a flow control block (while/if/for etc.). An arbitrary {} pair enclosing an arbitrary block of code also constitutes a stack frame. Any local variable defined within a frame will go out of scope once the program exits that frame. When a stack variable goes out of scope, its destructor is called.

When it is created in heap, it should be destructed by calling "delete" on the object

Taken from the [post](http://The%20objects%20in%20C++%20can%20be%20created%20either%20on%20the%20stack%20or%20on%20on%20the%20heap.%20%20A%20stack%20frame%20(or%20scope)%20is%20defined%20by%20a%20statement.%20That%20can%20be%20as%20big%20as%20a%20function%20or%20as%20small%20as%20a%20flow%20control%20block%20(while/if/for%20etc.).%20An%20arbitrary%20%7B%7D%20pair%20enclosing%20an%20arbitrary%20block%20of%20code%20also%20constitutes%20a%20stack%20frame.%20Any%20local%20variable%20defined%20within%20a%20frame%20will%20go%20out%20of%20scope%20once%20the%20program%20exits%20that%20frame.%20When%20a%20stack%20variable%20goes%20out%20of%20scope,%20its%20destructor%20is%20called.%20When%20it%20is%20created%20in%20heap,%20it%20should%20be%20destructed%20by%20calling%20%22delete%22%20on%20the%20object)