# when to use finalize in mongodb cxx r3.0.2 driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-cxx-driver

I am confused, in code snippets of [online doc,](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/mongocxx-v3/tutorial/#quick-start) it shows the usage of finalize when calling update_many method, like so:

```
mongocxx::stdx::optional<mongocxx::result::update> result =
 collection.update_many(
  document{} << "i" << open_document <<
    "$lt" << 100 << close_document << finalize,
  document{} << "$inc" << open_document <<
    "i" << 100 << close_document << finalize);
```

But I have seen the example code in mongocxx driver code without finalize

```
  // Update multiple documents.
    {
        // @begin: cpp-update-multiple-documents
        bsoncxx::builder::stream::document filter_builder, update_builder;
        filter_builder << "address.zipcode"
                       << "10016"
                       << "cuisine"
                       << "Other";
        update_builder << "$set" << open_document << "cuisine"
                       << "Category To Be Determined" << close_document << "$currentDate"
                       << open_document << "lastModified" << true << close_document;

        db["restaurants"].update_many(filter_builder.view(), update_builder.view());
        // @end: cpp-update-multiple-documents
    }
```

So what difference between using finalize or not using it? How to make a choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand the difference between the two construct, we need to understand the difference between [**Owning BSON Documents (values)**](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/mongocxx-v3/working-with-bson/#value) and [**Non-owning BSON Documents (views)**](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/mongocxx-v3/working-with-bson/#view) by diving into the source code and the [Working with BSON document](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/mongocxx-v3/working-with-bson/) page in the [documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/mongocxx-v3/).

*Owning BSON Documents* which type is [`bsoncxx::document::value`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/master/src/bsoncxx/document/value.hpp) represent those documents that own their buffer of data so when the  *value* goes out of scope, his buffer is freed. You can learn about [scope here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080935/when-is-an-object-out-of-scope) or even [better here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope) if it is new to you.

`finalize` returns a BSON document of type `bsoncxx::document::value` from a temporary buffer. So `finalize` returns an *Owning BSON Document*.

On the other hand, *Non-owning BSON Documents* are instance of [`bsoncxx::document::view`](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver/blob/master/src/bsoncxx/document/view.hpp); a view into an *Owning BSON Document*. And as mentioned in the documentation,

> In performance-critical code, passing views around is preferable to using values because we can avoid excess copying. Also, passing a view of a document allows us to use the document multiple times.

Also in the [**BSON Document lifetime**](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/mongocxx-v3/working-with-bson/#lifetime) explicitly mentioned with an example that

> It is imperative that `document::values` outlive any `document::views` that use them. If the underlying value gets cleaned up, the view will be left with a dangling pointer.