# Different ways to deallocate an array - c++

Tags: c++, arrays, memory-management

If you have said

```
int *arr = new int[5];
```

What is the difference between

```
delete arr;
```

and

```
delete [] arr;
```

I ask this because I was trying to deallocate memory of a 2d array and

```
delete [][] arr;
```

did not seem to work but

```
delete arr;
```

seemed to work fine

Thank you in advance!

Comment: That's an automatic or static array. In either case, invoking `delete` or `delete[]` is *undefined behavior*. So the "difference" is irrelevant. *Neither* would be correct. Does your book/tutorial seriously point you in that direction? Because if so, get a different one. [Related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4255598/delete-vs-delete).

Comment: sorry I meant arr to be a pointer. But yes my textbook suggest we use delete [] arr for an array.

Comment: On a *dynamic* array, certainly. On an automatic array, *no*. The short is, if you `new` you `delete`, if you `new [n]` you `delete[]`. That's it.

Comment: Understood I misunderstood the brackets for dimensions in an array,. So delete [] array would be good practice for a 2d array as well?

Comment: Again, if you used array-new then use array delete. If the "thing" you have was allocated with some form of `new []`, then `delete []` is to be used. And frankly, *none* of this is ideal [in modern c++ anyway](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6101039/Modern%20C%2B%2B.pdf).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`new type` requires `delete`
`new type[size]` requires `delete []`
Using one instead of the other is wrong.

Btw you should not use such raw pointers like this unless you have a very good reason. Use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead.

And 2D `M`x`N` arrays should generally be linearised into 1D `M*N` arrays, also using these containers.

Comment: Thank you, I am a fan of vectors but this was introduced in some hw and was a little confusing!

Answer (score 2):

> If you have said
>
> ```
> int arr[5];
> ```
>
> What is the difference between
>
> ```
> delete arr;
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> delete [] arr;
> ```

One has an extra pair of brackets in it. Both will probably crash and/or corrupt the heap. This is because `arr` is a local variable which can't be `delete`d - `delete` only works on things allocated with `new`.

`delete [][] arr;` is not valid syntax. For an array allocated with for example `new int[2][2]`, use `delete []`.

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the delete's is correct.

When you declare an array like this:

```
int arr[5];
```

The space is allocated on the `stack`. Memory allocated on the stack isn't cleaned by delete. It gets auto cleaned (Although clean is not the correct term technically) when the stack unrolls on exit of scope. (Check [When is an object "out of scope"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080935/when-is-an-object-out-of-scope) )

If you declre your array like this:

```
int *arr = new int[5]; // new allocates memory on heap
```

You call

```
delete[] arr; // this takes care of cleaning up memmory on **heap**
```

Comment: I am sorry I did mean int *arr = new int[5];

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean `new int[5]`, and the same `new` for dynamic memory. Otherwise, you are using stack, not the heap, and delete is undefined

While `delete arr` may seem to work for a 2-d array, I believe that the standard requires the following:

```
delete [] arr
arr=nullptr
```

This is because memory allocated with `new []` must be freed with `delete []` and vice versa. Also, it is dangerous to leave dangling pointers, hence the final line

Comment: okay do you think 'delete arr' would possibly delete only the row of the array and not the column?

Comment: Oh. Sorry. I made a mistake there. I forgot that i is contained within array